# r: function with lag working across rows, not columns

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I'm writing a function that will take the most recent observation and add it to the previous days values times a designated share of the previous observations. The below is a version that just uses one transformation and works:

```
df1<- data.frame(var1=rnorm(10,3,2), var2= rnorm(10, 4, 3))
df1$carryover<- lag(df1$var1, 1, default = 0)*(.5) + df1$var1
>df1

     var1       var2     carryover
1   3.2894474  2.0839128 3.2894474
2   3.6059389  7.8880658 5.2506625
3  -1.4274057  6.2763882 0.3755637
4   3.8531253  3.2653448 3.1394225
```

My function attempts to do the same but across multiple different shares, see below:

```
carryover<- function(x){
  result_df<- data.frame(x)
  xnames<- names(x)
  for (i in 1:7){
    result_column<- lag(x, 1, default = 0)*(i/10) + x
    result_column_name<- paste(xnames, i, sep= "_")
    result_df[result_column_name] <- result_column
  }
  return(result_df)
}
```

When I run `carryover(df1)`, `df$var1` remains the same across all iterations while `df1$var2` takes lag values across rows, when I'm aiming for columns. What is structurally wrong about my function that is causing it to not return lag the column values?

Comment: You are only changing one column. You need to specify another operation for `result_df[result_column]` if that is equivalent to `df$var1`. Only one of the columns is being updated.

Comment: edited the question, there's actually more to it: the function is somehow directing `lag` to lag across `rows` when I want it to lag across `columns`. Any advice there?

Comment: Yeah I'm not completely sure on how to solve this, but have you tried transposing?

Answer (score 0):

Worked on this a bit using feedback from Stackoverflow and came-up with the below solve, defining the the `carryover` function within a larger function, then using `apply` with `MARGIN=2` to calculate by column:

```
adStock<- function(x){
  # create datafame to store results in
  result_df<- data.frame(x)
  # assign names to be applied as a column
  xnames<- names(x)
  # create list of carryovers
  carryovers<- seq(.1, .7, .1)
  # create carryover function
  carryover<- function(x){
    x + dplyr::lag(x, 1, default = 0)*(i)
  }
  # run for loop across all carryover values
  for (i in carryovers){
    result_column<- apply(x, 2, carryover)
    result_column_name<- paste(xnames, i, sep= "_")
    result_df[result_column_name] <- result_column
  }
  return(data.frame(result_df))
}
```